# How to Create List and Display List in Textarea

Tags: javascript, html

I'm developing a food order system. I want show my order list in a textarea. Right now I can make list in a div's content. I also want my result price to be rounded at two decimal place like if you enter 2, it'll be formatted to 2.00.

My full code is a bit long.

This is a sample of the JavaScript I use :

```
function addNewItem() {
    price = 4.50;
    result += price;
    appendElement("container", "element" + price, "Cappucino Ice Blended " + price + "<a href=\"javascript:removeItem(" + price + ")\">[Remove]</a>");
    document.getElementById('sumOrder').value = result;
}
```

[The full code in a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/technique13/fvSuy/2/)

Answer (score 0):

To create new lines in the textarea, so that it looks like a list, you can delimit your orders with "\n".

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/U58gT/

```
<textarea id="orders" rows="10"></textarea>

<br /><br /><br />

<input id="new-order" type="text"><button>add order</button>

$('button').click(function() {
    var new_order = $('#new-order').val();
    $('#orders').append(new_order + "\n");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for reply but I using other method. I already can make list in text area. Now i got the problem to remove it when i click remove link. In DIV's i can remove properly but the textarea not remove. i using this code for make list in textarea.
This is a sample of the JavaScript I use :

```
    var result =0.00;
    function addtxt(input) {
        price = 4.50;
        result += price;
        var obj=document.getElementById(input)
        var txt=document.createTextNode("Cappucino Ice Blended "+ price+"\n")
        obj.appendChild(txt)
    addNewItem();}
    function addNewItem() 
    {
        appendElement("container", "element" + price, "Cappucino Ice Blended " + price + "<a href=\"javascript:removeItem(" + price + ")\">[Remove]</a>");
        document.getElementById('sumOrder').value = result;
    }

    function removeItem(price) 
    {
        result -= price;
        removeElement("container", "element" + price);
        document.getElementById('sumOrder').value = result;
    }
    function removeElement(parentId, elementId) 
    {
        var parentElement = document.getElementById(parentId);
        var childElement = document.getElementById(elementId);
        parentElement.removeChild(childElement);
    }
    function appendElement(containerId, newElementId, newElementContent) 
    {                   
        var newElement=document.createElement("div");
        newElement.setAttribute("id", newElementId);
        newElement.innerHTML=newElementContent;
        var container = document.getElementById(containerId);
        container.appendChild(newElement, container);
    }
```

[The full code in a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/technique13/8P9Zn/)